# Convert NZMG coordinates to lat/long

Tags: r, coordinate-transformation, proj

I have a bunch of NZ Map Grid coordinates, which I want convert to lat/long. [Based on this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/converting-nzmg-or-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-for-use-with-r-map-library), here is what I tried.

```
library(sp)
options(digits = 11) # to display to greater d.p.
```

Attempt 1:

```
proj4string <- "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41.0 +lon_0=173.0 +x_0=2510000.0 
+y_0=6023150.0 +ellps=intl +units=m"
p <- proj4::project(c(2373200, 5718800), proj = proj4string, inverse=T)
```

Attempt 2

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1), x = c(2373200) , y = c(5718800))
sp::coordinates(dat) = ~x+y

sp::proj4string(dat) = CRS('+init=epsg:27200') 
data_wgs84 <- spTransform(dat, CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
print(data_wgs84)
```

If I run my coordinates through the [linz coordinate conversion tool](https://www.geodesy.linz.govt.nz/concord/index.cgi) I get a slightly different result, which is the "true" result.

```
Results:
171.30179199  -43.72743909  # attempt 1 - ~200m off linz 
171.30190004, -43.72577765  # attempt 2 - a few meters off linz
171.30189464, -43.72576664  # linz
```

Based on [Mike T's](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/116682/110079) answer I should be using a "distortion grid transformation method" and he links to a "nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb grid shift file".

My Question: Is it possible to do this conversion using R without downloading additional files (nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb)? I want to share my code with others without them having to download any additional files.

Any advice much appreciated.

Comment: The linked answer is pretty clear: for best accuracy you need a file. Note that you have already done the conversion in R without the file, you just have to decide whether the reduced accuracy is good enough for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it is pretty simple, if you have the `rgdal` package installed, the required `nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb` file is included and you don't need to download anything extra.

You just need to use the full PROJ.4 string as outlined in [Mike T](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/20389/converting-nzmg-or-nztm-to-latitude-longitude-for-use-with-r-map-library/116682#116682)'s answer.

```
dat <- data.frame(id = c(1), x = c(2373200) , y = c(5718800))
sp::coordinates(dat) = ~x+y

proj4string <- "+proj=nzmg +lat_0=-41 +lon_0=173 +x_0=2510000 +y_0=6023150 
+ellps=intl +datum=nzgd49 +units=m +towgs84=59.47,-5.04,187.44,0.47,-0.1,1.024,-4.5993 
+nadgrids=nzgd2kgrid0005.gsb +no_defs"

sp::proj4string(dat) = sp::CRS(proj4string) 
data_wgs84 <- sp::spTransform(dat, sp::CRS('+init=epsg:4326'))
as.data.frame(data_wgs84)

id          x            y
1 171.3018946 -43.72576664
```

Which is the same as the output from the LINZ coordinate conversion tool. Hopefully this saves someone else a bit of time.